# About $\in$-Recursion and Mostowski Collapse

Tags: set-theory, recursion

The principle of $\in$-Recursion is a consequence of the regularity axiom. The formulation I know is:

> $\in$-Recursion: Let $G: V \to V$ be a class function, defined everywhere. Then there is a unique class function $F: V \to V$ such that $\forall x(F(x) = G(F \restriction x))$.

How does this theorem adapt to set functions?

The Mostowski Collapse Lemma says that

> Mostowski Collapse: Let $X$ be a set such that $(X, \in )$ satisfies the axiom of extensionality. Then there is a unique transitive set $M$ and a unique isomorphism $\pi: (X, \in)\to (M, \in )$.

To prove the lemma, we define $\pi(b) = \{ \pi(a) : a \in b \land a \in X\}$. Is this a case of $\in$-recursion? If so, what should be $G$ that defines $\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely a definition by $\in$-recursion (on $X$). Your $G$ here is the range function: $G(f) = \{b: (a,b)\in f\}$ (assuming $f$ is a function... zero or some other default value otherwise).

Comment: I made a typo, thanks. I don't get it, what function is $f$?

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável It is just the notation I chose for the argument for the $G$ function. (i.e. it is a variable). I have renamed it $f$ to make it more clear that we expect to pass $G$ a function (in fact some restriction of the $F$ function).

Comment: And also, let $m$ be the $\in$-minimal element of $X$, is $\pi(m) = \emptyset$?

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável Yes.

Comment: I just can't see how and everywhere defined class funtion can define a function in a set, particularly in this way. Do you have any useful references I could search?

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável Just ignore the values you don't need (e.g. we sent $G$ to zero everywhere the range function didn't make sense). I think this would be covered in any intro book on set theory. Try the old Kunen or Hrbacek/Jech.